# Formatting thousand separator for numbers in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to write a dataframe to a csv and I would like the .csv to be formatted with commas. I don't see any way on the to_csv docs to use a format or anything like this.

Does anyone know a good way to be able to format my output?

My csv output looks like this:

```
12172083.89 1341.4078   -9568703.592    10323.7222
21661725.86 -1770.2725  12669066.38 14669.7118
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
12,172,083.89   1,341.4078  -9,568,703.592  10,323.7222
21,661,725.86   -1,770.2725 12,669,066.38   14,669.7118
```

Comment: Unclear question, by default `to_csv` uses commas as separators so you need to post raw data, your code to recreate your df, what you've tried, the result from that, and the desired result

Comment: I think you're mixing up csv and thousand separators

Comment: Needless to say, if you're going to sprinkle commas into a *comma*-separated-values file, make sure to specify a non-comma symbol for the separator `sep` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comma is the default separator. If you want to choose your own separator you can do this by declaring the sep parameter of pandas to_csv() method.
`df.to_csv(sep=',')`

If you goal is to create thousand separators and export them back into a csv you can follow this example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[12172083.89, 1341.4078,   -9568703.592,    10323.7222],
[21661725.86, -1770.2725,  12669066.38, 14669.7118]],columns=['A','B','C','D'])
for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x : '{0:,}'.format(x))
df.to_csv(sep='\t')
```

If you just want pandas to show separators when printed out:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,}'.format
print(df)
```

Comment: What about ints? I can't figure out an integer format option.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do has nothing to do with csv output but rather is related to the following:

```
print('{0:,}'.format(123456789000000.546776362))
```

produces

```
123,456,789,000,000.546776362
```

See [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Also, you'd do well to pay heed to @Peter 's comment above about compromising the structure of a csv in the first place.